# Can't turn on X-Pack Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack

```
"version" : {
    "number" : "6.6.2",
    ...
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  }
```

Need to set password for Elasticsearch.
Try:

1. Goto /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml and add `xpack.security.enabled: true`
2. `service elasticsearch restart`
3. Goto /usr/share/elasticsearch and `bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive`
   Output:

   **Unexpected response code [404] from calling GET http://127.0.0.1:9200/_xpack/security/_authenticate?pretty
   It doesn't look like the X-Pack security feature is available on this Elasticsearch node.
   Please check if you have installed a license that allows access to X-Pack Security feature.
   ERROR: X-Pack Security is not available.**

Comment: can you try hitting `http://127.0.0.1:9200` and if it ask for username/password then it means x-pack is enabled.

Comment: Tried, not asking

Comment: can  you provide the startup logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, x-pack basic feature was added in 6.8, need to confirm and if that's the case then it explains the error as you are using 6.6, will find a link and update the exact version when x-pack basic version was introduced.

Just checked and looks like it was available in 6.3 according to [opening of x-pack](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/open-x-pack)